# Elegant alternative to after_create callbacks in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract
  after_create :mark_contract_as_live
  def mark_contract_as_live
    k = self.contract
    if !k.is_live
      k.update_attributes(:is_live => true)
    end
  end
end
```

is_live is a boolean field in the Contract model. A contract is defaulted to not live (is_live => false) when it created. When the first transaction is recorded it is marked as live (is_live => true). With the solution, I have above, it means that every transaction creation requires calling the database to check whether contract is live. Is there an alternative to this?

If contract has thousands of transactions, that means this will be called thousands of times although it is only relevant to the very first transaction.

In a general sense, what is an elegant way to implement callbacks. This seems messy?

Comment: I think this comes down to a question of class responsibility. It's up to a Contract to 'decide' if it's live or not; so create all transactions through an instance of contract and mark it live then; or don't record an 'is_live' boolean at all and simply define is_live? as transactions.limit(1).count > 0 (or some more efficient alternative)

Comment: Well, are you creating thousands of transactions all at once (during one Rails request)?  If not, then you shouldn't worry about the extra 1 or 2 queries.

Comment: @DavidGrayson yep, that's the part I didn't get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions

  def mark_as_live
    update(is_live: true) unless is_live?
  end
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract

  after_create :mark_contract_as_live

private

  def mark_contract_as_live
    contract.mark_as_live
  end
end
```

It is the `Contract` class responsibility to care if a contract should be marked as live or not. The `Transaction` class should not handle this. So I created a `mark_as_live` in the `Contract` class and call it in the `Transaction` `after_create` callback.

I would prefer to use a guard clause in the `mark_as_live` method like so:

```
def mark_as_live
  return if is_live?

  update(is_live: true)
end
```

But because it is a very short method, it probably does not worth it.

Note also that `ActiveRecord` adds methods like `xxx?` for boolean field. A question mark at the end of the method conveys more clearly what you want to say.

Finally, but this is a question of taste, I dislike prefixing my boolean attributes with `is_xxx`. I don't use `RSpec` and may be wrong but I think that it adds some predicate matchers like `be_xxx` for the `xxx` attribute and it may go weird with the `is_xxx` attributes. Because a lot of people are using `RSpec`, it may become a bit of a convention.

> If contract has thousands of transactions, that means this will be called thousands of times although it is only relevant to the very first transaction.

The `Contract` instance will be still loaded if you create a transaction like so: `contract.transactions.create(transaction_params)`. So the call to `is_live?` will come at no cost, you don't have to worry.

Comment: Side note, you don't need the guard clause, since ActiveRecord won't bother persisting if the attribute hasn't changed.